# mocked method returning undefined

Tags: jasmine

i am working on jasmine unit tests for angular and the mocking is not working. The junit code is:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    menuSpy = spyOn(menuService, 'getMenus');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should test menu', () => {
    spyOn(menuSpy, 'shouldHighlight').and.returnValue(true);
    menuSpy.and.returnValue(MENUS);
    // component assertions code
  });
```

and the component is as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './menu.component.scss' ]
})
export class MenuComponent {
    menus = []
    constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {
       menus = menuService.getMenus(); // menus is always undefined
    }
```

menus here is always null. I am stuck here all day. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are mocking your methods after they are already used in the constructor. You should move your mocks before the `TestBed.createComponent` call. You can try something like:

```
it('should test menu', () => {
    spyOn(menuSpy, 'shouldHighlight').and.returnValue(true);
    spyOn(menuService, 'getMenus').and.returnValue(MENUS);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MenuComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
   // Component assertions 
  });
```